# How to get the GPS data of a MacBook Pro using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gps

AFAIK every MacBook Pro has a GPS chip built-in, which e.g. can be used by Chrome to locate the user.

How can I access the user's position using Node.js?

Comment: The Macbook Pro does not have a GPS chip built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Macbook Pro has no builtin GPS but you can use its IP adress to try to determine its location.

There's a NodeJS API for MaxMind at https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip